# Swift Unsafe Mutable Addressor Crash

Tags: ios, swift, static, singleton

I am using custom nodes to manager a flow in my iOS app, and am getting an `SomeNode.one.unsafeMutableAddressor` crash when trying to access the first node and not sure why. This is the full error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` on the `one` node.

My nodes are setup like this, am I doing something wrong?

```
let firstNode: Nodes = .one
let node = firstNode.getNode()

class SomeNode {
    let number: Int!
    let next: SomeNode?
    
    init(number: Int, next: SomeNode?) {
        self.number = number
        self.next = next
    }
    
    static let one = SomeNode(number: 1, next: two) // Error highlighted here when trying to access the first element of the flow
    static let two = SomeNode(number: 1, next: three)
    static let three = SomeNode(number: 1, next: four)
    static let four = SomeNode(number: 1, next: nil)
}

enum Nodes {
    case one
    case two
    case three
    case four
    
    func getNode() -> SomeNode {
        switch self {
        case .one:
            return SomeNode.one
        case .two:
            return SomeNode.two
        case .three:
            return SomeNode.three
        case .four:
            return SomeNode.four
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I copied the exact same code snippet, added `print(Nodes.one.getNode().number);` and it logs `1`. How do you access it?

Comment: @AhmadF just by calling ```SomeNode.one``` I am getting a crash. not sure why

Comment: The crash itself is likely coming from `!` in the `let number: Int!`. Probably in some code you didn't post here, the `init()` for the `SomeNode` is called, and since it has no `number` at that point, it will crash. 
But since you are providing a value for `number` in `init`, you don't need to force unwrap it. So remove `!` and see if it solves it.